# how can i increase the speed of socket

Tags: python, sockets

how can i increase speed of socket in python ? 
my code :

```
import urllib
proxies = {'http': 'http://75.21.47.2:8080/'}
opener = urllib.FancyURLopener(proxies)
r = opener.open("http://www.python.org/")
print r.read()
```

Comment: Without seeing some code and/or an explanation, it is very difficult to answer this question. You might want to accept some answers, too.

Comment: What do you mean by 'speed of socket'? If this is UDP or TCP socket transfer speed, without further info; my answer would be: __Buy a better internet!__

Answer (score 2):

`75.21.47.2:8080` seems to be a public HTTP proxy server? these are invariably slow because of what they are.

If you want better performance via a proxy, implement your own or use a commercial service.

Answer (score 0):

Measure all stages of the pipeline (Opening the connection, sending the message, receiving the response etc.). Figure out where the largest bang for the buck is and think of a way to do it. From your question, the only answer is Kimvais's - **Buy a better internet!**

Answer (score 0):

Thought about compression? Sure, depends on what you're doing, but if possible it should definitely be used.

Answer (score -1):

What is the baud rate you are using? You can probably increase it.

Ok, now once the question has been cleared, I shall recommend to opt for a better solution (like implementing your own) rather than using the public proxy service. It is slow.

Comment: If any one is down voting, please put your feedback.